Convolution with a pathological distribution
Problem definition
Consider the following random bivariate vector
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
y&=z+v \\
z&\sim p_z(z;c) \\
v&\sim p_v(v)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $p_z$ depends on some parameter $c$. Assuming $z$ and $v$ independent, the density of $y$ is given by the two equivalent convolutions
\begin{equation}
p(y;c)=\int p_z(y-v;c)\,p_v(v)\,\mathrm{d}v=\int p_z(z;c)\,p_v(y-z)\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}
Let $p_v(v) \triangleq \mathcal{N}(y; 0, R)$, and assume that $z$ is uniformly distributed over a segment with vertices $c \triangleq {V_1, V_2}$. My problem is to compute $p(y;c)$. I argue that this problem is pathological because $z$ is distributed over a set with zero area.
What I've done
Since $z$ is uniformly distributed over the segment identified by $V_1, V_2$, we have
\begin{equation}
p_z(z;c) =\frac{1_c(z)}{\lVert V_2 - V_1 \rVert}
\end{equation}
where $1_c(z)$ gets unitary value over the segment and zero outside. Using the second convolution, it turns out
\begin{equation}
p(y;c)=\frac{1}{\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert} \underbrace{\int 1_c(z)\,\mathcal{N}(y-z; 0, R)\,\mathrm{d}z}_{\triangleq I(y)}
\end{equation}
so, the problem is to compute $I(y)$. A lot of options comes to my mind to compute such integral.

Monte Carlo 1: the searched integral can be written in the following form
\begin{equation}
\tag{$\star$}
I(y)=\int 1_c(z)\,\mathcal{N}(z; y, R)\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}
which can be seen as the expectation of $1_c(z)$ when $z\sim\mathcal{N}(z; y, R)$. This fact suggests to approximate the integral as follows
\begin{align}
I(y)\approx I_1(y)&\triangleq\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N 1_c(z_i)\\
z_i &\sim \mathcal{N}(z; y, R)
\end{align}
Monte Carlo 2: ($\star$) can be written in the following form
\begin{equation*}
I(y)=\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert \int \mathcal{N}(z; y, R)\, \frac{1_c(z)}{\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert}\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation*}
which can be seen as the expectation (scaled by $\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert$) of $\mathcal{N}(z; y, R)$ when $z\sim p_z(z; c)$ . This fact suggests to approximate the integral as follows
\begin{align}
I(y)\approx I_2(y)&\triangleq\frac{\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \mathcal{N}(z_i; y, R)\\
z_i &\sim p_z(z;c)
\end{align}
Trapezoid: the searched integral can be written in the following form as well
\begin{equation}
I(y)=\int_{D(c)} \mathcal{N}(y; z, R)\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}
where $D(c)$ is the set of points belonging to the line segment. Parametrizing the domain $D(c)$ is a trivial task
\begin{equation}
D(c)=\{z(\alpha)=(V_2-V_1)\alpha+V_1\}_{\alpha \in [0,1]}
\end{equation}
using this parametrization, it turns out the following line integral
\begin{equation}
I(y)= \int_0^{1} \mathcal{N}(y; z(\alpha), R)\,\lVert \dot{z}(\alpha)\rVert \,\mathrm{d}\alpha
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\dot{z}(\alpha)\triangleq \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}=V_2-V_1
\end{equation}
Then,
\begin{equation}
I(y)= \lVert V_2 - V_1\rVert \underbrace{\int_0^{1} \mathcal{N}(y; z(\alpha), R)\,\mathrm{d}\alpha}_{\triangleq \tilde{I}(y)}
\end{equation}
the new integral $\tilde{I}(y)$ can be computed with any numerical method, for example the trapezoidal rule. In this case, we have
\begin{align}
\tilde{I}(y) &\approx \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \frac{f(\alpha_{i+1})+f(\alpha_{i})}{2} \Delta \alpha\\
f(\alpha)&\triangleq \mathcal{N}\left(y; z(\alpha), R\right)\\
\alpha_i &\triangleq \frac{i-1}{N-1}\\
\Delta \alpha &\triangleq \frac{1}{N-1}
\end{align}
in the end, the approximation considered here is given by
\begin{equation}
I(y)\approx I_3(y)\triangleq  \lVert V_2 - V_1\rVert\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \frac{f(\alpha_{i+1})+f(\alpha_{i})}{2} \Delta \alpha
\end{equation}

Discussion
I've written some code to test my approximations. Let's assume that everything is correct; then, the three approximations should reach a consensus $I_1(y) \approx I_2(y) \approx I_3(y)$ as $N \to \infty$, thus providing the correct answer for $I(y)$. However, my code indicates that $I_1(y) = 0$, $I_2(y) \approx I_3(y) > 0$. The point is that this result makes perfect sense to me, and this fact is giving me a big headache (I'm excluding that the code is bugged - but I can be wrong).
Clearly, $I_2(y)$ and $I_3(y)$ are nonnegative because they are weighted sums of nonnegative quantities. On the other hand, $I_1(y)$ vanishes because the relative approximation counts how many times the sampled point $z_i \sim \mathcal{N}(z; y, R)$ falls over the segment connecting $V_1$ and $V_2$. This number has to be zero because the area of the segment is null.
I'm missing something somewhere and would like to have a hand in solving my misunderstandings.

Version #1 is incorrect in that this integral is not an expectation against a $\mathcal N(y,R)$ distribution. The fact that the random variable $Z$ is constrained to the segment $c$ means that the function $\mathcal{N}(z; y, R)$ appearing within the integral has to be interpreted as a density (up to a normalising constant) over that segment, rather than a standard Normal density.

I still have some issues with this problem. Let's say that $c$ is a square. Then, $Z$ is still constrained to $c$, but now the integral in version #1 is an expectation against $\mathcal{N}(y, R)$ (uncostrained distribution). In this non-pathological case where $c$ has positive area, versions #1, #2, and #3 provide equivalent results. Can you help me understand where the flaw in my reasoning is?

Simply because the support $c$ of $Z$ is of measure zero against a Normal $\mathcal{N}(z;y, R)$ density. A Monte Carlo approximation to the integral$$\int_cp_z(z;c),p_v(y-z),\mathrm{d}z$$can only exploit distributions that are absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure on $c$, i.e. densities $f$ in$$\int_c\frac{p_z(z;c),p_v(y-z)}{f(z)}f(z),\mathrm{d}z$$

Let's say $z,v,y\in\mathbb{R}^d$. The statement $z$ is uniformly distributed along the segment line from $V_1$ to $V_2$ is equivalent to saying $z=V_1-u\,(V_1-V_2)$ with $u\sim U[0,1]$, almost surely. Thus:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_y(y) = \int p_z(z)\,p_v(y-z)\,\text{d}z &= \int_0^1 p_u(u)\,p_v\left(y-V_1+u\,(V_1-V_2)\right)\,\text{d}u,\\
&= \int_0^1 p_v\left(y-V_1+u\,(V_1-V_2)\right)\,\text{d}u.
\end{aligned}
$$
Let $A=y-V_1$ and $B=V_1-V_2$, then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_v\left(y-V_1+u\,(V_1-V_2)\right) = (2\pi)^{-d/2}(\det R)^{-1/2}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(A+uB)^\top R^{-1}(A+uB)  \right].
\end{aligned}
$$
The argument of the exponential, up to the $-1/2$ factor, decomposes as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(A+uB)^\top R^{-1}(A+uB) &= (A+uB)^\top R^{-1}A + u(A+uB)^\top R^{-1}B,\\
&= A^\top R^{-1}A+ uB^\top R^{-1}A + uA^\top R^{-1}B    + u^2B^\top R^{-1}B,\\
&= A^\top R^{-1}A +2uA^\top R^{-1}B+ u^2B^\top R^{-1}B,\\
&= A^\top R^{-1}A-\frac{(A^\top R^{-1}B)^2}{B^\top R^{-1}B}+\frac{\left(u-\frac{A^\top R^{-1}B}{B^\top R^{-1}B} \right)^2}{(B^\top R^{-1}B)^{-1}},
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrating away the exponential of the third term times $-1/2$ gives:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_0^1\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\left(u-\frac{A^\top R^{-1}B}{B^\top R^{-1}B} \right)^2}{(B^\top R^{-1}B)^{-1}} \right]\, \text{d}u\\
&\,= (2\pi)^{1/2}(B^\top R^{-1}B)^{-1/2}\left[\Phi\left(\frac{\frac{A^\top R^{-1}B}{B^\top R^{-1}B}}{(B^\top R^{-1}B)^{-1/2}}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{\frac{A^\top R^{-1}B}{B^\top R^{-1}B}-1}{(B^\top R^{-1}B)^{-1/2}}\right) \right],\\
&\,= (2\pi)^{1/2}(B^\top R^{-1}B)^{-1/2}\left[\Phi\left(\frac{A^\top R^{-1}B}{(B^\top R^{-1}B)^{1/2}}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{A^\top R^{-1}B-B^\top R^{-1}B}{(B^\top R^{-1}B)^{1/2}}\right) \right],
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard Gaussian. Then, putting all together one gets:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 p_y(y) &= (2\pi)^{(1-d)/2}(\det R)^{-1/2}|\!|V_2-V_1|\!|^{-1}_{R^{-1}} \\
&\,\times \exp\left[  \frac{1}{2}\frac{\langle y-V_1,V_2-V_1\rangle^2_{R^{-1}}}{|\!|V_2-V_1|\!|^{2}_{R^{-1}}} -\frac{1}{2}|\!|y-V_1|\!|^{2}_{R^{-1}}\right],\\
&\,\times \left[\Phi\left(\frac{\langle y-V_1,V_2-V_1\rangle_{R^{-1}}+|\!|V_2-V_1|\!|_{R^{-1}}^2}{|\!|V_2-V_1|\!|_{R^{-1}}}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{\langle y-V_1,V_2-V_1\rangle_{R^{-1}}}{|\!|V_2-V_1|\!|_{R^{-1}}}\right) \right],
\end{aligned}
$$
where $|\!|x|\!|_{R^{-1}}=(x^\top R^{-1} x)^{1/2}$ is the vector norm induced by positive definite symmetric matrix $R^{-1}$, and $\langle x_1,x_2\rangle_{R^{-1}}=x_1^\top R^{-1} x_2$ is the inner product induced by $R^{-1}$.

I've tested your formula and seems to agree with my Monte Carlo 2 and trapezoid formulas. Can you provide more details about the change of variable from $z$ to $u$?
I'm trying to find a relation with this formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Vector_to_scalar

Morever, I think there is a typo in the first formula,  if I'm not wrong the sign of  under the sign of integral $u(V_2-V_1)$ should be negative.

I'm not sure if I have correctly understood your point. In my opinion should be
$z=(V_2-V_1)u+V_1$ and the change of variable from $z$ to $u$ should introduce the scaling factor $\lVert \dot{z}(u)\rVert=\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert$. Then, such scaling factor should cancel out with $1/\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert$ that was generated by $1_c (z)/\lVert V_2-V_1\rVert$

Yes, you're definitely right. Those factors cancel from the beginning. I updated the resulting formulas.
